# Category product on Homepage

Tags: magento-1.9

i want to limit category product on home page i use product_count,limit,Column_count but nothing work

Comment: Add this in collection 
$size=5;
$collection->setPageSize($size)

Comment: in blcok? or in phtml fille

Comment: where product collection prepare(block)

Answer (score 1):

Add set page size in product collection

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('visibility', 4)->setPageSize(5)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('../..')->getCollection()
                    ->setPageSize(10) // limit to 10
                    ->setCurPage(1);
```

Or

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('../..')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->limit(10); // limit to 10
```

Comment: but this will effect category pages

Comment: Wich collection are you using and where ?

Comment: getLoadedProductCollection on new cat page for home page

Comment: $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());

Comment: If you have created your own collection in a custom block, it should affect just that collection